# Customized Execution status in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

In Robot Framework, the execution status for each test case can be either PASS or FAIL. But I have a specific requirement to mark few tests as NOT EXECUTED when it fails due to dependencies.

I'm not sure on how to achieve this. I need expert's advise for me to move ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Until a SKIP status is implemented, you can use [exitonfailure](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.9b2/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#stopping-when-first-test-case-fails) to stop further execution if a critical test failed, and then change the output.xml (and the tests results.html) to show those tests as "**NOT_RUN**" (gray color), rather than "FAILED" (red color).

Here's an example (Tested on RobotFramework 3.1.1 and Python 3.6):

First create a new class that extends the abstract class [ResultVisitor](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/robot/result/visitor.html):

```
class ResultSkippedAfterCritical(ResultVisitor):

    def visit_suite(self, suite):
        suite.set_criticality(critical_tags='Critical')
        for test in suite.tests:
            if test.status == 'FAIL' and "Critical failure occurred" in test.message:
                test.status = 'NOT_RUN'
                test.message = 'Skipping test execution after critical failure.'
```

Assuming you've already created the suite (for example with `TestSuiteBuilder()`), run it *without* creating report.html and log.html:

```
outputDir = suite.name.replace(" ", "_") 
outputFile = "output.xml"

logger.info(F"Running Test Suite: {suite.name}", also_console=True)
result = suite.run(output=outputFile, outputdir=outputDir, \
         report=None, log=None, critical='Critical', exitonfailure=True)
```

Notice that I've used **"Critical"** as the identifing tag for critical tests, and **exitonfailure** option.

Then, revisit the output.xml, and create report.html and log.html from it:

```
revisitOutputFile = os.path.join(outputDir, outputFile)
logger.info(F"Checking skipped tests in {revisitOutputFile} due to critical failures", also_console=True)
result = ExecutionResult(revisitOutputFile) 
result.visit(ResultSkippedAfterCritical())
result.save(revisitOutputFile)

reportFile = 'report.html'
logFile = 'log.html'
logger.info(F"Generating {reportFile} and {logFile}", also_console=True)
writer = ResultWriter(result)
writer.write_results(outputdir=outputDir, report=reportFile, log=logFile)
```

It should display all the tests after the critical failure with grayed status = "NOT_RUN":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do, robot only supports two values for the test status: pass and fail. You can mark a test as non-critical so it won't break the build, but it will still show up in logs and reports as having been run.

The robot core team has said they will not support this feature. See [issue 1732](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/1732) for more information.

Even though robot doesn't support the notion of skipped tests, you have the option to write a script that scans output.xml and removes tests that you somehow marked as skipped (perhaps by adding a tag to the test). You will also have to adjust the counts of the failed tests in the xml. Once you've modified the output.xml file, you can use [rebot](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#rebot) to regenerate the log and report files.

Comment: Hmm... Is there any possibility on the post-processing technique? I've a specific word in the message for the skipped ones (Like Not Executed).

Comment: @Vimal: You can certainly create your own logs and reports by reading the output.xml and excluding anything you want. You could either create your own report from scratch, or filter out the data from output.xml and then run rebot on the new output.xml.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the change to be made **for your log/report files** you should take a look [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#programmatic-modification-of-results) for implementing a SuiteVisitor for the `--prerebotmodifier` option. As stated by Bryan Oakley, this might screw up your pass/fail count if you don't keep that in mind.

**Currently it doesn't seem to be possible to actually alter the test-status before output.xml** is created, but there are [plans to implement it in RF 3.0](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/177). And there is a discussion for a [skip status](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2087)

Another **more complex solution** would be to create your own output file through implementing a [listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-listener-interface) to use with the `--listener` option that creates an output file as it fits your needs (possibly alongside with the original output.xml).

There is also the possibility to **set tags during test execution**, but im not familar with that yet so I can't really tell anything about that atm. That might be another possibility to account for those dependency-failures, as there are options to ignore certain tagged keywords for the log/report generation

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

Run Keyword If  ${blabla}==${True}  do-this-task   ELSE  log to console   ${PREV_TEST_STATUS}${yellow}| NRUN |

test not executed and marked as NRUN

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you can **SET TAG** to run whatever keyword you like (for sanity testing, regression testing...)

Just go to your test script configuration and set tags

And whenever you want to run, just go to Run tab and select check-box Only run tests with these tags / Skip tests with these tags

And click Start button :) Robot framework will select any keyword that match and run it.

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post images :(

Comment: I doubt that this answers my question.