# How to skip test cases execution if first test case fail in robot framework

Tags: automation, robotframework

I am running multiple test cases (within a test suite) in robot framework. If the first test case setup section fails, then I want to skip the execution of all the remaining test cases.

Please let me know if there is any way to do that?

Comment: I found the answer here very useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25079032/1971003

Answer (score 3):

There is a command line option for this, the option is "--exitonfailure"
Here if any critical test case fails, the test execution stops immediately.

Comment: how you please include an example on how to use this --exitonfailure option?

Comment: Try `robot --exitonfailure mytests.robot`

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to skip some tests depending on the failure of a given test. That might be implemented in the future as it is being [discussed in an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2087).

In the meantime, what you can do is have a suite that groups your tests and in the Suite Setup, do some initial checks/verification (that would be similar to the test failure you mention). If the Suite Setup fails, then the tests of the suite won't be run.

Comment: That's good point. I would say  particular test cases should be independent. I.e. failure of one test (even in setup phase of the test) shouldn't touch other tests.

Answer (score 2):

Until a [SKIP](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2087) status is implemented, you can use [exitonfailure](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.9b2/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#stopping-when-first-test-case-fails) to stop further execution if a critical test failed, and then change the output.xml (and the tests results.html) to show those tests as "**NOT_RUN**" (gray color), rather than "FAIL" (red color):

[image]

I've already posted how to implement it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55745118/658497